# Sonarqube badge not working on github README

Tags: github, sonarqube, badge

Recently I wanted to add badges to an enterprise GitHub repository I order to have an overview of the Sonarqube statuses like coverage or quality gate.

> The issue is that the badges generated by the Sonarqube server(I am using a Sonarqbe server not Sonarcloud) do not show the image when added to the GitHub repository.

I tried using the api from Sonarqube but there isn't any call that helped.

Do you have any idea which I can try to make the images visible from a Sonarqube server to a repository from GitHub enterprise?

Comment: Is the project in question `Private`?

Comment: It's private from the outside of the company network, as for my colleagues from the team is not private.

Comment: Is it marked "private" in the SQ interface? Metric badges aren't available for private projects.

Comment: From what I know it's private for people outside the company beeing a Sonarqube enterprise installation. I don't know exactly if the project itself is marked as "private". From what I looked I didn't find anywhere if the project is set to "private"(maybe my user does not see those details). Does this affect the badges when used on Git?

Comment: Enterprise servers do not seems to support badges well. Unless I'm logged into our enterprise server, the badge's link are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was that for the badges we were using the URL with http instead of https and that's why the badges images weren't displayed. After we changed the URL to https we got the badges images to be displayed.

Comment: They don't work on private instances too... Even with HTTPS.

Comment: This answer does not work according to the original question. If the project is private http or https will not solve the badge image being broken.

Comment: FYI - you can get badges with 9.2 version https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-9-2/

Comment: This makes sense and I had a similar problem, but we still get a cross origin issue in Azure Devops repos

Answer (score 1):

FYI - This feature is now available with [SonarQube 9.2](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-9-2/) version.

From there official documentation.

**Badges for private projects and other long-awaited features**

*SonarQube 9.2 includes a number of long-awaited features to help you better integrate SonarQube into your organization. First, with this version we've finally been able to deliver badges for private projects. Next, is the new functionality to delegate administration of a single Quality Gate. Previously, administrators could delegate permissions for all Quality Gates; now they can be more selective. Speaking of delegation, delegating authentication to Bitbucket Cloud is now built in.*

Answer (score 0):

To get the SonarQube Badges in the readme.md are two configuration settings important.

- "Force user authentication" in Administration -> Configuration -> General settings -> Security, has to be set to false
- The SonarQube project has to be public

(tested on SonarQube version 8.9 LTS)

Comment: Depends on the version. Latest version does not.